# How do I list every file in a directory except those with specified extensions?

Tags: grep, find, ls

Suppose that I have a folder containing **.txt**, **.pdf**, and other files.  I would like to list the "other" files (i.e., files not having the extensions **.txt** or **.pdf**). Do you have any advice on how to do this?

I know how to list files not having a given extension.  For example, if I want to list all files except the **.txt** files, then either

```
find -not -iname "*.txt"
```

or

```
ls | grep -v '\.txt$' | column
```

seem to work.  But, how can I list everything except **.txt** files *or* **.pdf** files?  It seems that I need to use some sort of logical "or" in `find` or `grep`.

Comment: Keep in mind that the behavior of `ls` vs `find` vs globbing may differ for hidden dotfiles.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind: `find` will traverse subdirectories, like a recursive `ls`.  Use `-maxdepth 1` with `find` to get it to behave more like `ls`.

Comment: So no recursive, just list the files in current dir ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Assuming one has GNU `ls`, this is possibly the simplest way:

```
ls -I "*.txt" -I "*.pdf"
```

If you want to iterate across all the subdirectories:

```
ls -I "*.txt" -I "*.pdf" -R
```

Comment: GNU `ls` options aren't portable.

Comment: `ls` doesn't really belong in portable scripts anyways, so I've been assuming the OP is asking about interactive use only.

Comment: Why ls isn't portable? What should I use then?

Answer (score 40):

Find supports `-o`

```
find . ! '(' -name '*.txt' -o -name '*.pdf' ')'
```

You need the parenthesis to make the precedence right. Find does a lot of stuff; I suggest reading through its manpage.

You can also do an or in `grep` (but really, you [should not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs))

```
ls | grep -Ev '\.(txt|pdf)$' | column
```

Comment: Thanks!  Why shouldn't I parse the output of `ls`?

Comment: @Andrew first, because its fragile (consider a file name with a newline in it—yes, that's a valid file name—find's -print0/-exec/-delete/etc. avoid that problem); second, because there is usually an easier way.

Comment: In addition to the `find` manpage, I wholeheartedly recommend the Unix Power Tools articles about `find`, such as http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch09_06.htm and http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch09_12.htm

Comment: Just to help decode the statement for humans: `find . NOT ( *.txt OR *.pdf )`

Answer (score 15):

With `bash` extended globbing (turn on with `shopt -s extglob`), the glob `!(*.txt|*.pdf)` should work.  You can pass this glob directly to any command that takes file arguments, including but not limited to `ls`.

Comment: +1 but if you've subdirectories then their contents would be listed too; use `-d` to avoid that: `ls -d !(*.txt|*.pdf)`

Comment: Thank you, I was looking exactly for the syntax to accept multiple files, this would fit well here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216995/how-can-i-use-inverse-or-negative-wildcards-when-pattern-matching-in-a-unix-linu

Answer (score 6):

In `zsh` with `extendedglob`:

```
print -rl -- *~*.(txt|pdf)
```

or

```
print -rl -- ^*.(txt|pdf)
```

Or with `kshglob` (yes, that is ksh globbing not "bash extended globbing"):

```
print -rl -- !(*.txt|*.pdf)
```

Remember though that those also exclude dot files.

ksh93 has the `FIGNORE` (mis)feature:

```
FIGNORE='@(.|..|*.txt|*.pdf)'
printf '%s\n' *
```

Answer (score 5):

```
find /path/to/directory '!' -name '*.pdf' '!' -name '*.txt'
```

This is equivalent to the command with the OR operator, because of the [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by derobert, your best bet is to use `find`. However, you *can* in fact use the result in a pipeline with other commands.

GNU (and some BSD's) `find` support the `-print0` predicate which tells it to print the filename terminated by a *NUL* character, which character isn't allowed within a file name and guarantees there won't be a collision. Other commands can be instructed to use the *NUL* as their input delimiter.

The most important of which is GNU `xargs`, which runs the command you specify and passes to it the list of files as command line arguments. You want to run `xargs -r0` in conjunction with find's `-print0` For example:

```
find . -type f ! \( -name \*.pdf -o -name \*.txt \) -print0 | xargs -r0 ls -ld
```

This safely prints a long directory listing of all the *pdf* and *txt* files, including those with spaces or unprintable characters in the name.

You can also use it with GNU `tar` as follows:

```
tar -zcf myarchive.tar.gz --null --files-from <(
  find . -type f ! -name \*.tar.gz -print0)
```

This builds a tar.gz file of all the files whose names don't end in .tar.gz

`rsync` also accepts null-delimited files with the `-0` parameter, as do several others. But `xargs` is the glue you'll usually use for this type of purpose. Either that or `find`'s `-exec` feature.

Comment: The `tar` command example is a good one.  For most purposes, though, `-exec` is a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

As a complement, if you use a bash-compatible shell, you can use the GLOBIGNORE variable to exclure resuts from pattern matching. From the man:

```
   GLOBIGNORE
          A colon-separated list of patterns defining the set of filenames
          to be ignored by pathname expansion.  If a filename matched by a
          pathname  expansion  pattern also matches one of the patterns in
          GLOBIGNORE, it is removed from the list of matches.
```

In your particular case:

```
sh$ (GLOBIGNORE='*.pdf:*.txt'; ls -d *)
```

Please note I run that command as a sub-shell (using parenthesis) in order to not alter the GLOBIGNORE environment variable of my interactive shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a subdirectory

```
ls !(*.pdf|*.txt)
```

should also work!

But

```
ls -I "*.pdf" -I "*.txt"
```

is the common way.

Comment: These variations were already mentioned in answers from 2012.