# Command substitution in for loop not working

Tags: bash, grep, ls, cygwin, for

I want to keep all files **not** ending with `.bat`

I tried

```
for f in $(ls | egrep -v .bat); do echo $f; done
```

and

```
for f in $(eval ls | egrep -v .bat); do echo $f; done
```

But both approaches yield the same result, as they print everything. Whereas `ls | egrep -v .bat` and `eval ls | egrep -v .bat` work per se, if used apart from the `for` loop.

**EDIT**

It's interesting to see that if I leave out the `-v` flag, the loop does what it should and lists all files ending with `.bat`.

---

<sup>Feel free to edit the question title, as I was not sure what the problem is.</sup>

I'm using `GNU bash, version 4.1.10(4)-release (i686-pc-cygwin).`

---

**EXAMPLE**

```
$ ls -l | egrep -v ".bat"
total 60K
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM 5.3K Jun  6 20:31 fsc*
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM 5.3K Jun  6 20:31 scala*
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM 5.3K Jun  6 20:31 scalac*
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM 5.3K Jun  6 20:31 scaladoc*
-rwx------+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM 5.3K Jun  6 20:31 scalap*
```

Command is working, but not in the for loop.

```
$ for f in $(ls | egrep -v .bat); do echo $f; done
fsc
fsc.bat
scala
scala.bat
scalac
scalac.bat
scaladoc
scaladoc.bat
scalap
scalap.bat
scalac
scalac.bat
scaladoc
scaladoc.bat
scalap
scalap.bat
```

**DEBUG** `$ set -x`

```
mike@pc /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/scala/bin
$ for f in $(ls | egrep -v .bat); do echo $f; done
++ ls -hF --color=tty
++ egrep --color=auto -v .bat
+ for f in '$(ls | egrep -v .bat)'
+ echo fsc
fsc
+ for f in '$(ls | egrep -v .bat)'
+ echo fsc.bat
fsc.bat
// and so on
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you look at things in the following question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47151/how-do-i-list-every-file-in-a-directory-except-those-with-specified-extensions; _except_ all the solutions based on `ls`.

Comment: @Mat that doesn't explain how you should do it within a `for` loop.

Comment: @MBR Why did it work for you? Did you also use bash? Can anyone explain that?

Comment: @mike I am also using GNU bash (though a more recent version, 4.2.25). No idea why it works in my case and not in yours... Anyway, val0x00ff answer seems to be satisfying.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still interested in why exactly the fail occurred.

Comment: This works for me too. Why did you drop the double quotes wrapping ".bat" in the for loop?

Comment: Just by chance, it did not change anything though.

Comment: Applications such as the antivirus have been suggested as possible causes of this behavior in Cygwin. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48927435/cygwin-command-substitution-not-working

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A few things wrong in your code:

#### Using unquoted command substitution (`$(...)`) without setting `$IFS`

Leaving expansions unquoted is the split+glob operator. The default is to split on space, tab and newline. Here, you only want to split on newline, so you need to set IFS to that as otherwise that means that will not work properly if filenames contain space or tab characters

#### Using unquoted command substitution without `set -f`.

Leaving expansions unquoted is the split+glob operator. Here you don't want globbing, that is the expansion of wildcards such as `scala*` into the list of matching files. When you do not want the shell to do globbing, you have to disable it with `set -f`

#### `ls` aliased to `ls -F`

The issue above is aggravated by the fact that you have `ls` aliased to `ls -F`. Which adds `/` to directories and `*` to executable files. So, typically, because `scala` is executable, `ls -F` outputs `scala*`, and as a globbing pattern, it is expanded to all the filenames that start with `scala` which explains why it seems like `egrep -v` is not filtering files out.

#### Assuming filenames don't contain newline characters

newline is as valid a character as any in a filename. So [parsing the output of `ls` typically doesn't work](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). As for instance the output of `ls` in a directory that contains `a` and `b` files is the same as in a directory that contains one file called `a\nb`.

Above `egrep` will filter the lines of the filenames, not the filenames

#### Using `egrep` instead of `grep -E`

`egrep` is deprecated. `grep -E` is the standard equivalent.

#### Not escaping the `.` regex operator.

Above, you used `egrep` to enable *extended* regular expressions, but you don't use any of the extended RE specific operator. The only RE operator you're using is `.` to match any character, while it looks like that's not what you intended. So you might as well have used `grep -F` here. Or use `grep -v '\.bat'`.

#### Not anchoring the regexp on end-of-line

`egrep .bat` will match any line that contains any character followed by `bat`, so that's the regexp that means anything that contains `bat` not in first position. It should have been `grep -v '\.bat$'`.

#### Leaving `$f` unquoted

Leaving an expansion unquoted is the split+glob operator. There, you want neither, so `$f` should be quoted (`"$f"`).

#### Use `echo`

`echo` expands the ANSI C escape sequences in its arguments and/or treats strings like `-n` or `-e` specially depending on the `echo` implementation (and/or the environment).

[Use `printf` instead](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22565).

### So a better solution:

```
for f in *; do
  case $f in
    (*.bat);;
    (*) printf '%s\n' "$f"
  esac
done
```

Though if there's no non-hidden file in the current directory, that will still output `*`. You can work around that in `zsh` by changing `*` to `*(N)` or in `bash` by running `shopt -s nullglob`.

Comment: Okay, quite a few things I should improve. But to get it straight. The loop did not *fail* per se. The `grep` did work, but because of the `*` added by `ls -F` the variable `f` in `$f` got expanded. So either stop the expansion or remove the `F` flag from the `ls` command. The opposite command, i. e. without the `v` flag in grep, did work, because there was nothing to expand a file name matching `<filename>.bat*` to.

Comment: @mike, no, the wildcards (as added by `ls -F`) got expanded upon the command substitution (`$(...)`). If there had been a file called `scala*`, that wildcard would also have been expanded upon the expansion of `$f` (and you'd had seen all the filenames starting with `scala` separated by spaces on one line)

Comment: Oh, of course. That makes totally sense considering the debug output.

Answer (score 9):

You should not use `ls` to parse files this way.

First set extglob globstar by `shopt -s extglob globstar` then

```
for f in !(*.bat)
  do
   printf '%s\n' "$f"
  done
```

Using `find`

```
find . -type f ! -name '*.bat'
```

Use the negation operator for a safer treat of files.

Comment: I get `bash: !: event not found
`. Why shouldn't I use `ls` in that way?

Comment: because you have not enabled `extglob`  See above.

Comment: Thx! And for completness: one should not use `ls` in a for loop the way I did it, because some file names could contain newline characters.

Comment: You can even skip the loop entirely and use `printf '%s\n' !(*.bat)` (you can do the same with `rm`)

Comment: It was not about the printing. I wanted to dynamically create symlinks to the scala files. I guess that's also possible with `find` and `exec`, but looping was easier for me ;D

Comment: `globstar` is not needed here.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherently wrong with your for loop:

```
$ for f in $(ls | egrep -v .bat); do echo $f; done
```

Here's my output for the above command:

```
$ for f in $(ls | egrep -v .bat); do echo $f; done
fsc
scala
scalac
scaladoc
scalap
```

#### Possible fix

One suggestion would be to quote the argument to `egrep`, like so:

```
$ for f in $(ls | egrep -v '.bat'); do echo $f; done
```

Also take a look at the Bash Pitfalls wiki for other potential issues when scripting things in Bash such as this. In particular this sounds like the [most plausible reason](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) why you're encountering this problem. Check to see if any of your files being returned contain spaces.

#### Debugging

Another thing to try is to enable verbose debugging of your bash command, prior to running it so you can see what's going on behind the scenes.

This enables debugging:

```
$ set -x
```

Then run your command:

```
$ for f in $(ls | egrep -v .bat); do echo $f; done
++ ls --color=auto
++ egrep --color=auto -v .bat
+ for f in '$(ls | egrep -v .bat)'
+ echo fsc
fsc
+ for f in '$(ls | egrep -v .bat)'
+ echo scala
scala
+ for f in '$(ls | egrep -v .bat)'
+ echo scalac
scalac
+ for f in '$(ls | egrep -v .bat)'
+ echo scaladoc
scaladoc
+ for f in '$(ls | egrep -v .bat)'
+ echo scalap
scalap
```

Then disable it:

```
$ set +x
```

#### Issue with Cygwin?

Given the examples work fine on a number of native Linux systems the problem is most likely rooted in having something to do with Cygwin and/or it's particular versions of `bash` and `egrep`. I'd pay particular attention to the field separator in Bash, `$IFS` to see if there is an issue between the various line separators on Windows (`0x0d,0x0a`) vs. Unix (`0x0a`).

I do not have an installation of Cygwin so I have no method for proving this hypothesis.

Comment: I added debug data to the question. The single quotes did not change anything. The spaces are in the path name, but I'm doing a local operation here. The file names are spaces-free, I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: @slm, I have to disagree on `ls` use in the `for` loop context.`ls` is purely designed for the human eye. Different operating systems parse `ls` output differently.

Comment: @val0x00ff - on technical merits I 100% agree with you, but when doing one off scripts, I've done this exact thing and never had any issues. As long as you understand the implications as the operator it doesn't matter. Just my $0.02. If a script will only ever see the light of day on a single system, the different implementations of `ls` doesn't matter either.

Comment: @mike - what does `$IFS` look like? `echo $IFS`.

Comment: @slm ...edited this comment. It's not empty, it's a `\n`.

Comment: You're missing the fact that globbing is performed upon command substitution since it was not disabled and that `ls` was aliased to `ls -F`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I don't doubt you're right, but I've never grasped the subtlety of the ins/outs of what's going on here. If I swap in an `ls -F` to my example it still works. I don't understand your comment about the globbing being performed upon command substitution. I suspect others also miss these details and hence why seem to see this family of questions so frequently here. A canonical answer is definitely needed on this topic (you've pretty much started one with your A to this Q).