# Why does a working standalone nested function/script not work inside a larger script?

Tags: bash, scripting, function, variable-substitution

The following (nested) function/s

```
function hpf_matrix {

  # Positional Parameters
  Matrix_Dimension="${1}"
  Center_Cell_Value="${2}"

  # Define the cell value(s)
  function hpf_cell_value {
    if (( "${Row}" == "${Col}" )) && (( "${Col}" == `echo "( ${Matrix_Dimension} + 1 ) / 2" | bc` ))
      then echo "${Center_Cell_Value} "
      else echo "-1 "
    fi
  }

  # Construct the Row for Cols 1 to "Matrix_Dimension"
  function hpf_row {
    for Col in `seq ${Matrix_Dimension}`
      do echo -n "$(hpf_cell_value)"
    done
  }

  # Construct the Matrix
  echo "MATRIX    ${Matrix_Dimension}"
  for Row in `seq ${Matrix_Dimension}`
    do echo "$(hpf_row)"
  done
  echo "DIVISOR   1"
  echo "TYPE      P"
}
```

work/s fine, both as a standalone code and inside a script.  I.e. `hpf_matrix 5 18` will return

```
MATRIX    5
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 18 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
DIVISOR   1
TYPE      P
```

and it will even work (with various values) as requested in:

```
Kernel_Size=5
Center_Cell_Default=18 ; Center_Level=Default
eval Center_Cell="Center_Cell_${Center_Level}"

HPF_MATRIX_ASCII=`hpf_matrix ${Kernel_Size} ${!Center_Cell}`
echo "${HPF_MATRIX_ASCII}"
```

However, integrating without any changes the above pieces of code (the `hpf_matrix` function and feeding the `"${HPF_MATRIX_ASCII}"`) inside a larger bash script, errors-out with the following message:

```
((: 1
2
3
4
5 == 1
2
3
4
5 : syntax error in expression (error token is "2
3
4
5 == 1
2
3
4
5 ")
```

*Minor Update*

If I understand correctly, for whatsoever is the reason behind, the line

for Row in `seq ${Matrix_Dimension}`

as well as the line

for Col in `seq ${Matrix_Dimension}`

are printed as `"1 2 3 4 5"` instead of `"1" "2" "3" "4" "5"`.

**What is wrong in this case?**  I would like to keep a nested structure for the function unless it is clearly wrong.

Comment: @user528025 Using your one-liner I ended up to the function mentioned in this question. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6724056/1172302 ?

Comment: Problem resolved! It was the `IFS=,` instructed somewhere in the large script. This was messing things up, as well explained at: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88259/13011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the large script, in which the above function was integrated to work as part of it, and prior of defining the `hpf_matrix` function, the `IFS` has been changed to `IFS=,` without taking care to reset it back before using the *unquoted command substitution* in the function!

An explanation on *Using unquoted command substitution ($(...)) without setting $IFS* here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88259/13011.

A solution to this also here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92188/13011.