# Clearing folders except specific type of files

Tags: files, find

I have tree of folders as follow:

```
parent folder
....folder A
....folder B
    ....folder 1
    ....folder 2
....folder C
    ....folder 1
    ....folder 2
....folder D
    ....folder 1
    ....folder 2
. 
.
```

Inside every folder I have a punch of files. These files have different extensions (zip, tar.gz, jpeg, bmp, csv, xlsx, doc, txt, ...etc)

1. How can I delete all the files in the folders except the files *.jpeg.
2. How can I delete all the files in the folders except more than one type of file ( e.g. except the files *.jpeg , *.csv)

In order to achieve this I was thinking of using the command:

```
find . type -f -exec
```

But I don't know how to complete it!..

Any other ways to do it ?

Comment: `find . -type f ! -name \*.jpeg` to list them, add `-delete` if you're happy with the result

Comment: @don_crissti. Thanks! " -name \*.jpeg" does it means list all the files except *.jpeg. Kindly what "!" stands for?  if I want to exclude more than one type of files. How can I do it? Thank you very much for explaining it.

Comment: `!`  negates the `-name` test... `man find` for more details; as to excluding more than one type... please edit your post and state your exact requirements, don't add them via comments

Comment: This has been asked before but I can't find the exact duplicate, anyway for more than one extension see  _derobert_'s [`find` solution here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47153), to remove the files just add `-delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . type -f ! -name '*.jpeg' ! -name '*.csv' -delete
```

Read this as: traverse the current directory; when you find a file that is a regular file, and whose name does not match `*.jpeg`, and whose name is does not match `*.csv`, then delete it.

If your version of `find` doesn't have `-delete`, make `find` invoke the `rm` command: replacte `-delete` by `-exec rm {} +`.

In zsh (with `setopt extended_glob` turned on), `*~(PATTERN)` matches all files that don't match `PATTERN`. Use the [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `D` to include dot files and `.` to include only regular files. Change `.` to `^/` to delete all non-directories (except the ones matching the excluded patterns).

```
rm **/*~*.(jpeg|csv)(D.)
```